# Setting Values from one Dataframe to another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with this pandas dataframe and would like to essentially set what is in the `city` column of the `match` dataframe to the `ball_by_ball` dataframe if the IDs of the match in the `match` dataframe is equal to the ID in the `ball_by_ball` dataframe.

Match:
[image: SS of dataframe with matches]

Ball by ball for all matches:

[image: SS of dataframe with ball_by_ball details]
Data can be accessed **https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/patrickb1912/ipl-complete-dataset-20082020**

Some information on the dataframe:
the match dataframe contains the final results of any particular match ID, while ball by ball contains the information on said match ID.

I tried the following which does "work":

First creating an empty column by

```
city_ball["city"]=None #city_ball is the same as ball_by_ball
```

Followed by:

```
for id in range(len(match["id"])):
  for ID in range(len(city_ball["id"])):
    if match["id"][id] == city_ball["id"][ID]:
        city_ball["city"][ID] = match["city"][id]
```

But i understand this is a terrible way of implementing it, so I'm looking for suggestions to implement it efficiently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a textbook use case for a join or merge, but the first thing I think of is to *map* each ID to its city using [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
# Build a Series which maps each id to a corresponding city.
# Drop duplicates to ensure each distinct id only appears once
id2city = match.drop_duplicates(subset='id').set_index('id')['city']

# Apply the mapping to each id in the target DataFrame
city_ball['city'] = city_ball['id'].map(id2city)
```

Comment: df.join() doesn't work as far as I understand, because the two dataframes aren't of the same length. I'll however try what you have suggested and get back to you.

Comment: Let me know if this solution works! And it would be a sad and confusing world in which joins only worked on tables of equal length :)

Comment: Oh join does work, its just wouldn't be at the expected indexes is I suppose what I should've said, or atleast that's what it did when I tried. Also it worked like a charm, I thought I had edited my comment to show it already! I was completely unaware of the use of .map(), thanks for making it clear.

Comment: Nice, glad to hear this approach worked on your data!